# Waiting for Embedded Image to Load?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I'm trying to load a sprite sheet. I've embedded it into the .swf, but when I instantiate a class and call a function that starts clipping from the sprite sheet, I get the error:

"Parameter sourceBitmapData must be non-null."

I know that what is happening is that the code is being called before the sprite sheet image is actually loaded, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem since I'm embedding rather than using a loader. I assume I'll need to use event listeners, but how do I make that work with the embedding? Here's my code so far:

In the Main public class:

```
private var currentSprite:SpriteSheet;
[Embed(source='../assets/images/sprite_sheet_1.png')]
private var sheetClass:Class;
private var sheet:Bitmap = new sheetClass();
```

Then in the Main function:

```
currentSprite = new SpriteSheet( sheet, 25, 25 );
addChild(currentSprite);
```

The SpriteSheet function is set up like so:

```
public function SpriteSheet(tileSheetBitmap:Bitmap, width:Number = 25, height:Number = 25) {
    tileSheetBitmapData = tileSheetBitmap.bitmapData;
    tileWidth = width;
    tileHeight = height;

    rowLength = int(tileSheetBitmap.width / width );

    tileRectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight );
    tilePoint = new Point( 0, 0 );

    canvasBitmapData = new BitmapData( tileWidth, tileHeight, true );
    var canvasBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasBitmapData);
    addChild(canvasBitmap);

    drawTile(0);

    addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, remove);
}
```

In my SpriteSheet class, I call a drawTile function which calls copyPixels(), where the error is originating from:

```
canvasBitmapData.copyPixels(tileSheetBitmapData, tileRectangle, tilePoint);
```

I know that's a lot of code, but I feel there's probably a simple solution. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is the SpriteSheet class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SpriteSheet extends Sprite {
        public var tileSheetBitmapData:BitmapData;
        private var canvasBitmapData:BitmapData;

        private var tileWidth:int;
        private var tileHeight:int;
        private var rowLength:int;

        private var tileRectangle:Rectangle;
        private var tilePoint:Point;

        public function SpriteSheet(tileSheetBitmap:Bitmap, width:Number = 25, height:Number = 25) {
            tileSheetBitmapData = tileSheetBitmap.bitmapData;
            if(tileSheetBitmap != null ) {
                trace("tileSheetBitmap is not null in SpriteSheet");
            }
            if( tileSheetBitmapData != null ){
                trace("tileSheetBitmapData is not null in SpriteSheet");
            }
            tileWidth = width;
            tileHeight = height;

            rowLength = int(tileSheetBitmap.width / width );

            tileRectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight );
            tilePoint = new Point( 0, 0 );

            canvasBitmapData = new BitmapData( tileWidth, tileHeight, true );
            var canvasBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasBitmapData);
            addChild(canvasBitmap);

            drawTile(0);

            addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, remove);
        } //end of SpriteSheet

        public function drawTile(tileNumber:int):BitmapData {
            trace("Reached drawTile");
            tileRectangle.x = int( (tileNumber % rowLength) ) * tileWidth;
            tileRectangle.y = int( (tileNumber / rowLength) ) * tileHeight;
            canvasBitmapData.copyPixels(tileSheetBitmapData, tileRectangle, tilePoint);
            trace("Reached past copyPixels");

            return canvasBitmapData.clone();
        } //end of drawTile

        public function tileBoard(boardIndex:Array):BitmapData {
            var wide:int = boardIndex[0].length;
            var tall:int = boardIndex.length;

            canvasBitmapData = new BitmapData( (tileWidth * wide), (tileHeight * tall), true);
            var boardCanvas:Bitmap = Bitmap(getChildAt(0));
            boardCanvas.bitmapData = canvasBitmapData;

            tileRectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, (tileWidth * wide), (tileHeight * tall) );
            for( var i:int = 0; i < wide; i++ ) {
                for( var j:int = 0; j < tall; j++ ) {
                    tilePoint = new Point((tileWidth * i), (tileHeight * j) );

                    drawTile(boardIndex[j][i]);
                }
            }
            return canvasBitmapData.clone();
        } //end tileBoard

        public function remove(e:Event):void {
            tileSheetBitmapData.dispose();
            canvasBitmapData.dispose();
        } //end remove
    } //end class SpriteSheet
} //end package
```

Comment: Did you trace or debug your bitmapData at this point, or in the constructor?

Comment: There's a line in SpriteSheet in the main function where I call drawTile(0), and commenting that out gave me a new error:

    Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

In my Main function. So now I guess I need to trace why that's happening. Hmm.

Comment: You don't talk about drawTile in your question, please let's focus on this missing bitmapData :)

Comment: Right on. Give me just a minute to test whether the SpriteSheet object I create is null.

Comment: I was more thinking about figuring out whether tileSheetBitmapData and tileSheetBitmap were null.

Comment: The sheet Bitmap and currentSprite object both trace as non-null after creation in the Main function. But setting the tileSheetBitmapData to public and then using an if statement to check if it is null indicates that the bitmapData is in fact null after creating the SpriteSheet object.

Edit: Right. So the bitmap was there when I tested the sheet:Bitmap, but the tileBitmapData in the SpriteSheet class that accepts the bitmap is null.

Comment: I tried testing the bitmap within SpriteSheet as well, and the bitmap itself is not null. The bitmapData, however, is coming up null.

Comment: Just a thought here but maybe you have to wait for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event before you can access the data. currentSprite.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, function(e){trace(yourdatahere)});

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a loading issue, since you're embedding the png file into your swf, all the image loading is done while the swf is loaded.

this is a problem with the Flash IDE compiler only... With Flex compiler this is not necessary...

try:

```
private var sheet:BitmapData = new sheetClass(0,0);
```

change your SpriteSheet class to accept the bitmapData directly

Comment: `new sheetClass() as Bitmap` more likely no?

Comment: Tried the first suggestion and got the error: Error #1112: Argument count mismatch on class coercion.  Expected 1, got 0.

Then I tried Kodiak's addition and put: private var sheet = new sheetClass as Bitmap; and got the original error.

Comment: sorry, mine should've been 
    Bitmap(new Sheetclass());  (no new) Kodiak's way should work also.

Comment: Same error. Tracing sheet and it is not null, but interestingly enough, sheet.bitmapData is null. Don't quite understand.

Comment: also would be nice to know what your using to compile, Flex compiler (& version) or Flash IDE (& version)

Comment: & show us your list of imports, just to make sure the Bitmap type is the correct one.

Comment: Flash CS 5.5. My imports are:
flash.display.MovieClip;
flash.utils.Timer;
flash.events.TimerEvent;
flash.ui.Mouse;
flash.ui.Keyboard;
flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
flash.events.Event;
flash.media.SoundChannel;
flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;
 
flash.display.Sprite;
flash.geom.Point;
flash.geom.Rectangle;
 
flash.geom.Matrix;
 
flash.net.URLRequest;
flash.net.URLLoader;
 
flash.display.Bitmap;
flash.display.BitmapData;
flash.utils.ByteArray;
flash.geom.Rectangle;
 
com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
flash.events.MouseEvent;
flash.display.Loader;

Comment: try my edited answer, I think that's the problem (Flash IDE compiler specific)

Comment: I changed my SpriteSheet class accordingly, but it has a problem with the sheetClass itself. If I leave in the (0,0) it says it received 2 arguments and expected 0. If I change it to (), taking out the 0,0, it says it can't convert sheetClass to bitmapData.